# difference between export variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

what is difference between the two following export

```
export const xxx = {name:"andy"}
```

and

```
const xxx={name:"andy"}
export= xxx
```

in which position we have to use `export= xxx`

Comment: The second one is invalid. It should be `export {xxx}`. There is no runtime difference between those two.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. Maybe you're reading [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)?

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax if you don't want to export and declare at the same time  is :

```
const xxx = { name: "andy" };
export { xxx };
```

> in which position we have to use export= xxx

The position doesn't matter, so you could write this as well:

```
export { xxx };
const xxx = { name: "andy" };
```

That is because the `export` keyword works for hoistable declarations, as specified in [ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports-runtime-semantics-evaluation)